# Roo shell report "Unknown version" and hangs when executing any command in STS (eclipse)

Tags: spring-roo

I'm just starting into my first spring project with a group of other developers and we have spent most of the last two days scratching our heads with this one.  I have a clean MAC 10.9.3 with STS 3.4.0 installed along with Java 1.7 .  STS comes with ROO 1.2.4

Using the wizard and creating the DEMO project, everything comes up roses.  In particular, if I goto the "Project Explorer" and right click "Spring Tools" -> "Open Roo Shell" a Roo Shell opens and shows VERSION 1.2.4  I can type commands in the Shell, everything seems to work perfectly.

Here's where things get interesting:

If I "Import" the current in-house spring project (we are currently working on) using:
File -> Import -> General -> Existing projects into Workspace OR
File -> Import -> Maven ->Existing Maven Projects
Everything gets sucked into Eclipse and is built beautiful and runs with error
**BUT**
When I "Open Roo Shell" on this newly imported project (in Eclipse),  The roo shell opens BUT it reports:

"UNKNOWN VERSION"

If I execute any command in this "UNKNOWN VERSION" roo shell, the shell completely hangs

The logs reports no errors whatsoever

We've install command line maven and ran MVN clean.  Tried different versions of java.  setup JAVA_HOME, ROO_HOME and everything else we can think of.

Everything works perfectly on the other developer machines -- these were setup last year and everyone has been updating incrementally.  What are we missing with this fresh install?

?? Where is this UNKNOWN VERSION getting picked up.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Note you imported a non-Roo project and open the shell on that project, so Roo doesn't "recognize" that project.

Before open the shell you should move your project to Roo. Learn more at Roo guide http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/removing.html#removing-reversal, section "Reenabling Roo After A Removal".